# Generate HTML table with colors using Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm writing some code where I execute some tests and generate a report consisting of 4 columns and many rows. I want to visualize it in HTML using the Pandas "to_html" function which I have managed to but I want to color 2 of those columns either in red or green depending on whether the tests have failed or passed. Is there anyway I can modify the strings so that when I execute the "DataFrame.to_html()" function the bgcolor of the text is already applied?
Thank you

I tried using the style function but it would require me to locate every string I need to modify and then apply the style change, while I would rather insert the colored string directly considering that when I produce the row of the table I already know whether the cell should be green or red

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `B` holds the tests status and `A` & `D` the cols to be colored, you can use :

```
d = {"Failed": "lime", "Passed": "lightcoral"}
colors = df["B"].map(lambda v: f"background-color: {d.get(v)}")

s = df.style.apply(lambda _: colors, subset=["A", "D"]) # add/remove cols

# s.to_html() # uncomment to make an HTML
```

Output :

[image]

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(
    *[[*"ab"], ["Passed", "Failed"], [0, 1], [*"cd"]]),
                  columns=[*"ABCD"])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without having a column hold the test status but just by evaluating a condition?

Comment: Not only this is in contradiction with what you described in your post but you're also making me imagine how looks like your dataset. Show some effort and make an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).